# Accessing cells in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am working with a program and I need to access the data that is stored in cells, but I am not able to figure this out. This is what I know:

There are five matrices, X1, X2,...,X5.
A cell is created, C={X1 X2 ... X5}
Next we create the multiplication table c{i,j}=C{i}*C{j} for i,j=1:5
so c{i,j} is a 5by5 cell.
Finally, cx{i,j} is created by modifying each cell c{i,j}. Each element of cx{i,j} is composed  of the first two rows of each matrix element of c{i,j}, like this, 
cx{i,j}={c{i,j}(1,:) c{i,j}(2,:)}

So cx{i,j} is a 5 by 5 cell. I want to be able to type cx{i,j} into MATLAB and get the numeric value, but I just get the cell structure. I tried [cx{i,j}] but this doesn't work. What command allows me to get the numeric values? Thanks.

Comment: Can u provide some example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem:

```
>> cx{i,j} = {c{i,j}(1,:) c{i,j}(2,:)}
```

Create a `1x2` cell with two `1x5` vectors. It is NOT a `5x5` matrix.

Possible solution:
You can create `cx{i,j}` in the following manner

```
>> cx{i,j} = [ c{i,j}(1,:) ;c{i,j}(2,:) ]
```

Note the square brackets `[` and the semi-colon `;` that creates `cx{i,j}`.
Now, `cx{i,j}` is a `2x5` matrix, and it can be accessed and viewed by simply typing `cx{i,j}`.

A few comments

- For these types of problems (and many others) it is best to use Matlab's debugger to see exactly what is going on.
- It is best [not to use `i` and `j` as variable names in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).